# WPF -> Stretch Image Vertical

Tags: wpf, image, stretch

I try to implement a MapScrollBar into Avalonedit WPF Control. For this i need to Stetch a VisualBrush Vertical Only. That means It always should Resize Vertical so it fit's in a Container. And it Should be Uniform Stretched!. But when I ste the StretchMode to UniFormToFill. It Stretches Vertical or Horizontal until it fit's. Is there a way to get my desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now fixed it so:

```
                   <Border Grid.Row="1">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <VisualBrush RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Linear" Stretch="Fill" AutoLayoutContent="True">
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <ScrollViewer Width="800" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                        <rendering:TextView 
                                                MinHeight="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" 
                                                Document="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=Content.Document}" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
```

By putting it in a Scrollviewer with has a fixed Width, and a variable Height!